# Microsoft Graph REST API: Filter signIns by Country

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to query the Microsoft GRAPH REST API as follows:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signIns$filter=location/any(c:c/countryOrRegion eq 'CA')`

However I am receiving a **400: Invalid filter clause** error.

If I do a simple query such as `$filter=userDisplayName eq 'Bob Smith'` my query works fine.

What is the correct way to filter signIns by Country in Graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax for filter sub-property -
$filter=property/subProperty eq 'value-to-match'

You can try using below query

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/auditLogs/signins?$filter=location/countryOrRegion eq 'IN'
```

[image]

For more info you can check the docs for filter query parameters - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/filter-query-parameter